# add panel to frame from different class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, panel, frame

Okay tried to sum up my problem. Im trying to add a jpanel from a different Class. In that class I have print method where I get input from a file and append it to a JTextArea, which is the second block of code. I want to add that panel to the frame inside GUI class. The current code outputs the buttons in this first block correctly. But clicking options only expands the window a little and is all black. The buttons remain there but overlaying the black window. =(

```
package GamePackage;

import java.*;

import javax.swing.*

public class CopyOfGUI extends JFrame {
static String config = null;
static JFrame frame;
static JPanel panel;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CopyOfGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Sheep City");
    panel = new JPanel();
    JButton options = new JButton("OPTIONS"); 
    JButton start = new JButton ("START");
    JButton controls = new JButton ("CONTROLS");

    panel.add(options);
    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(controls);


    frame.add(panel);

    options.addActionListener(new actionReadConfig(config)); 

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) 
        {config = args[0];}
    CopyOfGUI gui = new CopyOfGUI();    

}
//Here is where the options button loads the read in argument for the config file
class actionReadConfig implements ActionListener {
    String config = null;
    public actionReadConfig(String config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            GameBoard.loadConfig(this.config);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Here is the code where im trying to add the text from the file read to a text area, add it to the panel, and it back to the original frame.

```
public static int print(ConfigurationManager cm) {
    //code gere
    JPanel configPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    configPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Configuration Manager"));
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.append("Before we get started lets setup our configurations shall we?\n");
    area.append("These are the default configurations.\n");
    area.append("*************************\n");
    //for loop here {
        //area.append output
    //}
    area.append("*************************\n");
    area.append("Would you like to change any of these values? (yes/no)\n");
    area.setEditable(false);
    configPanel.add(area, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //Idk if any of this is right 
    CopyOfGUI.frame.add(configPanel);
    CopyOfGUI.frame.remove(CopyOfGUI.panel);
    CopyOfGUI.frame.pack();
    CopyOfGUI.frame.setVisible(true);
    CopyOfGUI.frame.repaint();
```

More code afterwards but I need the previous part to work before I worry about the rest. Thx in advance.

Comment: Just an observation - it's pretty hard for anybody to help you when you write soo much and your code is still incomplete (e.g. who's calling the print method?). Try to be concise, reduce the problem to the bare minimum and provide some compilable code. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @aditsu thanks I tried to sum it up more but i think thats as short as I can make the code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the print method is called but you can make the panel a class variable and place it in a public getter so you can add it the frame (assuming the print method is in another class).

```
private JPanel configPanel;

public JPanel getConfigPanel()
{
    return configPanel;
}
```

Then you can use that method and add it to your frame:

```
frame.add(someClass.getConfigPanel);
```

Comment: That actually sounds like a great idea. I'll try that out and report back! Thank you!